# Syntax Error in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use `genvar` in verilog. Here is part of my code-

```
reg [31:0] q[0:3];
initial
begin
   genvar j;
   generate
   for(j=0;j<4;j=j+1) begin : loop1
      q[j]=32'H00000000;
   end
   endgenerate
end
```

This gives a syntax error-

```
Error:near "genvar":syntax error,unexpected "genvar"
```

How can I implement this?I want to initialize all `q` array with all zeros in all 32 bits. I want to do this through a loop as size of array can be very large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `generate` block is usually used along with `for` loops to mimic **multiple instants**.

You have used `generate` in the `initial` procedural block, which is obviously **illegal**. And hence the syntax error occurs. So, remove `genvar` and `generate` block.

To **initialize** the variable, there can be many methods. Some of them are as follows.

```
reg [31:0] q[0:3] = '{0,1,2,3}; // assigning default values

reg [31:0] q[0:3];
initial
begin                        // weird method
   for(j=0;j<4;j=j+1) begin : loop1
      q[j]=32'h00000000;
   end
end

reg [31:0] q[0:3];
initial
begin
  q='{default:'0}; // initialize all elements to zero
end

reg [31:0] q[0:3];
initial
begin
  foreach(q[i]) // can be preferable
    q[i] = 0;
end
```

Refer to SystemVerilog [LRM 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) for more info on generate block.